# Internet works only on recovery mode but does not work on normal boot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04

Every thing was working well, but suddenly internet stopped working on my laptop. When i log in using recovery mode the internet works but on normal boot internet does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Boot in recovery mode
2. Enable networking there (it will start!)
3. Resume (continue to normal boot)
4. Ignore any problems, i.e. with
   graphic driver - networking still works without the NetworkManager
5. Run synaptic package manager (easiest way) or another similar tool.
6. In the list of installed packages select three linbl-* packages
7. All of these three probable have version of 3.2.21-1ubuntu1 from trusty-proposed
8. You should downgrade them downto version 3.2.21-1 from trusty (not ...proposed!)
9. reboot
10. enjoy!

Another ways of this solution can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727914/network-disabled-after-update-kernel-to-3-13-0-77-generic-on-ubuntu-14-04-1/727996).

If you will not bother yourself with package managers, you may download these three files from [my hubiC](http://ovh.to/iw98ccE) Link will be active to February 10, 2016 (hubiC's limitation)